# How to apply animation in sweet alert 2 when closing the modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, sweetalert2

Does anyone know how to apply animation to sweet alert 2 on close? It appears the `function(dismiss)`doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
$.ajax({
  method:'POST',
  url:'sql/record.php',
  data:formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response){
    swal({
      title: 'Success!',
      text: "New record has successfully added.",
      type: 'success',
      animation: false,
      customClass: 'animated tada',
      showCancelButton: false,
      confirmButtonText: 'OK'
    }).then(function(result){
    }, function(dismiss){
      swal({customClass: 'animated bounceOut'});
    }
  });
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question, but maybe someone is still looking for answer (like I was).

I managed to apply animation to closing and confirming swal2. This method does not work for clicking outside of swal to dismiss it.

```
swal({
    title: 'swal title',
    html: 'some content',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    animation: false,
    customClass: "animated fadeInLeft",
    onClose: function(){
        return delaySwalWithAnimation("fadeInLeft","fadeOutRight");
    },
    preConfirm: function(){
        return delaySwalWithAnimation("fadeInLeft","fadeOutRight");
    }
}).then(function(result) {
    //...
}

function delaySwalWithAnimation(animationToRemove, animationToAdd){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        $(".swal2-popup").removeClass(animationToRemove);
        $(".swal2-popup").addClass(animationToAdd);
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
        },300);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an attribute called `onClose`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  method:'POST',
  url:'sql/record.php',
  data:formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response){
    swal({
      title: 'Success!',
      text: "New record has successfully added.",
      type: 'success',
      animation: false,
      customClass: 'animated tada',
      showCancelButton: false,
      confirmButtonText: 'OK',
      onClose: function(modal) {
         modal.className += ' animated bounceOut';
      }
    })
  });
);
```

Comment: This reads promising but unfortunately I couldn't get it working as the modal closes immeditately when the close button is pressed and before the event fires. Any idea how to work around this? I consider making a custom close button but would appreciate if there's an easier way.